# Show/Hide Bokeh widgets based on another widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have a checkbox A that has two options, and I want to display different widgets based on the options. So when click option 1 only widgets B shows, and click option 2 only widget C shows. I was able to hide widgets B and C with `css_classes = ['hidden']` but don't know how to make them show conditionally. I figured it to be something like this:

```
if 0 in Checkbox_A.active:
  wiget_B.show()
else:
  widget_C.show()
```

Comment: The widgets should have a `visible` property you can set to `True` or `False`. Have you tried that instead of setting CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bokeh, you can either link the whole models together or link signals. Assuming you're using `bokeh serve`, something like this will work:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Div, CheckboxGroup

d1 = Div(text="First widget")
d2 = Div(text="Second widget", visible=False)
c = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Display the first widget"], active=[0])


def checkbox_changed(attr, old, new):
    b = (new == [0])
    d1.visible = b
    d2.visible = not b


c.on_change('active', checkbox_changed)

curdoc().add_root(column(c, d1, d2))
```

But it's possible to do something like that purely on the JavaScript side.